# How to drag a pushpin and get location using Bing Maps in Windows 8.1?

Tags: c#, windows-8.1, bing-maps

I am currently working on Bing Maps in Windows 8.1 App in which there is a requirement to drag a pushpin and when it is dropped get the location. The pushpin which I am using is a third party control which I found after a little search on Google. But as I am new to Windows 8.1 development, I am not much aware about the touch events and how to handle drag events. Can anyone suggest me with some sample code how I can do this.

Please help.

Also, when displaying location I am facing zoom in and out issue, the pushpin moves away from its location. Here is my code for displaying location

```
Map map = frameworkElement as Map;
map.Credentials = "My Bing Maps Key";
//map. = MapCartographicMode.Road;
map.ZoomLevel = 15;
Bing.Maps.Location location = new Bing.Maps.Location()
{
    Latitude = Convert.ToDouble(value.GetType().GetRuntimeProperty("LATITUDE").GetValue(value, null)),
    Longitude = Convert.ToDouble(value.GetType().GetRuntimeProperty("LONGITUDE").GetValue(value, null))
};
MapLayer layer = new MapLayer();
map.Children.Add(layer);
MapControl.Pushpin pushpinPin = new MapControl.Pushpin();
pushPin.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
pushPin.Margin = new Thickness(-12, -12, 0, 0);
TextBlock Nametxtblk = new TextBlock()
{
    Text = value.COUNCIL_NAME,
    Width = 250,
    TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap,

};
pushPin.Content = Nametxtblk;
MapLayer.SetPosition(pushPin, location);
//MapLayer.SetPositionAnchor(pushPin, new Point(Width/2, Height/2));
layer.Children.Add(pushPin);
map.SetView(location);
break;
```

Here, MapControl.Pushpin is a third party control, which I am using to display location.

**Update**

I am adding my pushpin image below. Please suggest.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have a code sample of how to create draggable pushpins in Bing Maps on Windows 8.1 here: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Draggable-Pushpin-in-Bing-939eaaa5

Comment: I saw this sample on msdn but I want to create it without using user control. Is it possible to change your code a little and explain me how I can achieve my requirement. It would be a great help.

Comment: Not using a user control is an option but would make things a bit messier. You would need to write a bunch of code that uses the events on the Pushpin class. You should be able to port a lot of it over from my code sample. If the pushpin class you are using isn't sealed you could try adding extensions to make things a bit cleaner.

Comment: Thanks rbrunditt. I will check this. Could you suggest about the Zoom in and out issue, I have added code also.

Comment: Your zooming issue is a fairly easy one. The issue is that the point your pushpin that is anchored to your coordinate is incorrect, this causes a drift effect. You can use margins to reposition your pushpin so that the correct point of your pin aligns with your coordinate. Here is a blog post on this topic: https://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2014/10/02/correcting-anchoring-pushpins-to-the-map/

Comment: I tried to set negative margin, but it didn't helped. The issue is, pin is anchored at the top left corner and not at bottom. If you need my push pin image I can show you.

Comment: try larger margin values. The should work unless your pushpin class overrides the margins somewhere.

Comment: I have added an image of my pushpin . Please suggest from that. The pushpin has a Content parameter in which I have added a TextBlock and showing the address by reverse geocoding to user.